# How to copy cells with red font, not row?

Tags: excel, vba

I am working with a tutorial. It works when all the text in the row has red font.

I need to:

1. Select the cells with red font and copy those only not the entire row and also put the cell in same position on the new sheet it copies to.
2. Copy into new sheet the code value in the row Col A.

[image: mock-up]

The current code:

```vb
Sub CopyColouredFontTransactions()

    Dim TransIDField As Range
    Dim TransIDCell As Range
    Dim ATransWS As Worksheet
    Dim HTransWS As Worksheet
    Dim x As Long
    
    Set ATransWS = Worksheets("All Transactions")
    Set TransIDField = ATransWS.Range("A2", ATransWS.Range("A2").End(xlDown))
    Set HTransWS = Worksheets("Highlighted Transactions")
    
    For Each TransIDCell In TransIDField
    
        If TransIDCell.Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) Then
           
            TransIDCell.Resize(1, 10).Copy Destination:= _
                HTransWS.Range("A1").Offset(HTransWS.Rows.Count - 1, 0).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
               
        End If
    
    Next TransIDCell
    
    HTransWS.Columns.AutoFit

End Sub
```

Comment: Don't resize the range, just copy one cell at a time

Answer (score 1):

like this:

```vb
For Each TransIDCell In TransIDField
    If TransIDCell.Column = 1 Or TransIDCell.Font.Color = vbRed Then
        TransIDCell.Copy HTransWS.Range(TransIDCell.Address)
    End If
Next TransIDCell
```

Comment: thanks working partially but 3 things 1. Have Some Cells with Red Text which were not copied
2. Copying Rows with no Red Text Values in them with Col A code. Need so only time code in Col A gets copied is if any of the cells in that row have Red Text 
3. Copying Rows With Red Background aswell

Comment: #1 Maybe they're not exactly "red" but a slightly different shade: vbRed or RGB(255,0,0) is very precise color  #2 Your example didn't show any skipped rows so it's not clear what should happen when a row has no red text  #3 Code only looks at font color, so I've no idea why a cell with only a red background might be copied.  Maybe update your question with a more-representative screenshot, and explain what should happen when a row has no red text?

Comment: another possibility for #1 may lie in the formatting (typically red for negative numbers) or conditional formatting. These will not be affected by the if condition `TransIDCell.Font.Color = vbRed`.

Comment: If you're using conditional formatting to apply the red color then you need to look at `DisplayFormat.Font.Color`.  Likewise a cell with red text which had a CF format of black text with red fill applied would still match on `TransIDCell.Font.Color = vbRed`

Answer (score 0):

Im actually new to vba and I kinda wanna try solve it. I got the output that you want but with a bit spin off on the method of execution. Feel free to comment about this.

```
Public Sub ClearNorm()
Dim xlw As Worksheet
Dim range_1 As Range

  For Each range_1 In Range("B2:D4")
      If range_1.Font.Color <> vbRed Then
        range_1.ClearContents
   End If
  Next range_1
  Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy Sheets(2).Range("A1")
Sheets(2).Activate

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank for reply but not getting any output with this

Comment: Hello, sorry for that. I have changed the code u can try if u want